# How to automate the process of executing a command upon creation of a file

Tags: files

How to **automate** the process of executing a command upon **creation of a file**.
I have an application wherein a tool generates an xsd schema from a xml file. My next module uses this xsd schema for further processing.
I want to automate this process i.e. to run a command once the file is generated. This application will run **everyday** on ubuntu machine so I want to automate it. I don't want any human intervention in this process.
I did search inotify lib which is used for similar purposes but it forces me to change the enitre design of my system.
Are there any other alternatives which would solve this purpose? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out when the file is finished being written is the hard part. It is best to use a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
program-that-creates-xsd
program-that-does-further-processing
```

There really aren't any good solutions if you can't structure your program like this. Even with inotify, it is nearly impossible to tell when the XSD is truly finished.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting file creation in a specific folder can be done via `inotifywait` which is part of `inotify-tools` package installable via `sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`.

As an example, we can establish a continuous watch (`-m` flag) on directory `Desktop` and parse the output for created directory entries, however determining if a file is regular file and filename is the one we need has to be done manually:

```
inotifywait -m --format "%f" -e create ./Desktop/  | 
while read -r fname; do 
    [ -f ./Desktop/"$fname" ] && [ "$fname" = "specific.csv" ] && echo "We got 'em!" 
done
```

So in case someone makes directory `specific.csv` that should be rejected, but if `specific.csv` is created we will execute `echo` portion, which could be replaced with other commands or shell functions. If you do need a non-blocking execution, you might consider adding `setsid` to start the command in new session and let the script continue watching.